# How to find out number of downloads on my Alexa skills

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I released an Alexa app for my company. I wish to find out number of people downloaded my skills.

I can track all the queries coming in to the application through Cloud Analytics in AWS. But there is no information about number of devices running my skills.

Are there any third-party tools that should be integrated to get this information?

I'd appreciate your help, advice and guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

A revised skills dashboard has recently been published to the Amazon Developer Portal that offers much more functionality than the former 'Skills Metric' page as described in Option 2 below. You can navigate there via your skills list in the Amazon Developer Portal. Details in [this blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/2b3912a9-c6ec-4642-9c1a-55c42d0f14b6/leverage-the-new-metrics-dashboard-to-deepen-skill-engagement-drive-retention1?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTUdNMllURTBOVEF3WkRNMiIsInQiOiJkNmRwenJNbkNIUlJCN3FOc04ySUVVUFIzTGx0aDZGNE9GdURHVHZUb3lGVldFZFZ5V082WWptc2hLNFRaUW4wYVA4NXdabjFyQlVkTjdoNmZVMDdIb2h0RTlIRDBYRUxFUHhQZmVcL2djNUpzZ1k0WHJIbThuNWYrNnp0d0RnT1gifQ%3D%3D).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

### Option 1) Publish Your Own Metrics

Each request body sent to your alexa skill contains a `userId` that you can use to track distinct users. From the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#request-format):

> userId: A string that represents a unique identifier for the user who made the request. The length of this identifier can vary, but is never more than 255 characters. The userId is automatically generated when a user enables the skill in the Alexa app.
>
> Note: Disabling and re-enabling a skill generates a new identifier.

So this does have a caveat -- `userId` will change for a given install if the user disables and re-eanbles your skill -- but it generally describes distinct users.

This bit of data can be written out of your skill to any logging aggregator and used to build your own metric.  If your service lives in AWS Lambda, perhaps the simplest way to do this would simply to [log it out to CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html) via `console.log()`, and work from there.

### Option 2) Alexa Skill Metrics

Amazon publishes "Total Utterances Count" and "Unique Customers Count" to the Amazon Developer Portal.

As of this writing, there is no API to access these counts. These metrics are also not available for Flash Briefing or Smart Home skills. Hopefully both of these points will change some time in the future.

Announcement from the [Amazon Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/2762/new-feature-skill-metrics.html):

> - Total Utterances Count – Number of requests sent to your skill over a time range
> - Unique Customers Count – Number of customers your skill has over a time range
>
> Metrics data is updated on an hourly basis, and can be viewed in Hourly, Daily or Weekly intervals.

#### Navigate to Skill Metrics

In order to get to the "Skill Metrics" page:

- navigate to the Alexa section of the developer console
- select the "Skill Metrics" tab

**Screenshot:**

[image]

#### Skill Metric Dashboard

The Skill Metric Dashboard is controlled by a navigation bar that allows you to control:

- Time Interval: Time interval in UTC (example: 2017-04-02 20:00 - 2017-04-03 20:00:00)
- Aggregation Period: Aggregates the counts into hourly/daily/weekly buckets
- Skill Stage: Toggle metrics between "Development" and "Live" skill
- Language: Toggle metrics for a specific language (example: English (U.S.) vs. English (U.K)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: have you noticed that the total values change per aggregation period? Why is that?